# Rabbitmq ready and unack messages

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a queue with 50 consumers and the prefetch count of around 100. All the consumer is from single JVM instance. So, when the application goes down, the messages were in READY state. The number of messages in ready state is equal to (prefetch_count * no. of consumers).

Now the question is, what will happen to the messages in READY state? Will it redelivered or will it get dead lettered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be redelivered.

Messages will only be dead-lettered if the consumer specifically rejects (nacks) the message with `requeue=false` (and the queue is configured for dead-lettering).

Comment: Thanks Gary!! When will it get redelivered? Consider this scenario, when two instances of Java running each registered itself as 50 consumers to queue and prefetch count is around 100. Lets say one instance of Java goes down. The messages which are consumed by dead instance is in READY state. What will happen to these messages? When will it get redelivered?

Comment: When the broker detects the connection is closed, any messages that are UNACKED are transitioned back to READY. Messages that were READY at the time of the failure (and not unacked - because both consumer prefetches were full) will be processed AFTER the requeued messages.